# (extjs 6.0+)How can panel dynamically modify layout

Tags: extjs, layout

My extjs version is 6.0+; The original layout of panel used to be 'hbox'. Now I want to change it to 'VBox'. 
What shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `hbox` you can change it to `vbox` layout  chaging the vertical value of its layout configuration  using `setLayout()` method, eg:

```
let myPanel = Ext.getCmp('myPanelId'); // get the reference of the panel you want to modify
myPanel.setLayout({
    vertical: true
})
```

Sadly you can't change the type of your layout dynamically. You must instead recreate your component and change its layout from there:

```
Ext.create('My.Panel', {
    layout: 'fit'
})
```

See the  [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/316e)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,if i want to change 'cloumn' or 'table'( layout) ,haw can i do?

Comment: Updated to answer with more details about changing the type of layout, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.